# Cannot publish single self-contained file in dotnet core 3.1

Tags: .net-core

I want to try out .net core for the first time, so I downloaded the newly released .net core 3.1 lts.
I need to publish a single self-contained file but it doesn't work. Neither via the gui of VS nor via the command line

```
dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release /p:PublishSingleFile=true
```

the deployment is self-contained, yes, but it contains 200+ files and not 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The self-contained single executable is located in the /publish subfolder. My bad, apologies for not appreciating the generated output sufficiently.