# I have created HelloWorld console application using .net core 3.1 Which file should I deploy to Linux so that I can run the console application there?

Tags: c#, cross-platform, asp.net-core-3.1

I have created HelloWorld console application using .net core 3.1 Which file(.dll or exe) should I deploy to Linux so that I can run the console application there? I have published this app as self contained and copied the HelloWorld.dll file to Redhat Linux and got an error '-bash: HelloWorld.dll: command not found'

Comment: The .exe file is the executable.

Comment: I don't think you can deploy either the .exe or .dll files to linux. Those sound like Windows executables, linux would have its own (I believe .a).

Comment: @RobertHarvey He's trying to run it on Linux.

Comment: are you copying the output of the /publish directory? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59563968/105566

Comment: I tried to copy the entire publish folder to Linux, it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the runtime using the `--runtime` flag with `dotnet build`

```
dotnet build --runtime rhel.7-x64
```

Comment: so I did this and it got Build Successfully. So should I just copy the rhel.7-x64 file to Linux?

Comment: Sorry for late update, this worked. I had the target publish set to linux-x64. This created  a folder linux-x64 and pasted the entire folder in Linux. It ran successfully.